# Designing a class whose dependancies require "starting"/initializing step

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, single-responsibility

I have **Facade** class which requires an **Endpoint** instance to function (it uses it in most of the functions). Endpoint is attached to **Platform** that is passed in Endpoint's constructor and has to be started (Platform.Start()). Both Platform and Endpoint come from external library and use **Start/Stop** pattern. Before Facade is operational, Platform and Endpoint have to be initialized and started. Constructing Facade class requires user to provide few **runtime** parameters which are required for constructing Platform/EndpointSettings.

What is the best place to construct and start Platform and Endpoint in Facade class? Starting Platform/Endpoint are operations that could take up to few seconds and could fail for various reasons.

Which of these designs would be most appropriate given the situation:

1. Initialize and start Platform/Endpoint in Facade's **constructor**.
2. Start Platform/Endpoint in Facade's **Start method**.
3. Use **builder pattern** to construct the Facade and initialize/start Platform/Endpoint in Build method.
4. Use **factory pattern** to construct the Facade and initialize/start Platform/Endpoint in Create method.

Constructing/starting Platform/Endpoint are relatively complex and require things like getting certificate from the certificate store. If Builder/Factory are used; is this "too much work" for them?
.

```
public class Platform
{
    public Platform(PlatformSettings platformSettings)
    {
    }
    public void Start()
    {
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
    }
}

public class Endpoint
{
    public Endpoint(Platform platform, EndpointSettings endpointSettings)
    {
    }
    public void Start()
    {
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
    }
}

public class Facade
{
    private readonly Endpoint _endpoint;

    public Facade(string somePlatformSetting,
        string someEndpointSetting,
        FacadeSettings facadeSettings)
    {
        //(Method 1) Initialize and start platform and endpoint here?
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //(Method 2) Initialize and start platform and endpoint here?
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
    }

    public void DoOperationOnEndpoint()
    {
        //_endpoint.DoSomething...
    }
}
```

Comment: If starting Platform/Endpoint fails, would it then be logical that there can not be an instance of Facade or would it be more logical that the user of the Facade object retries the Start operation at a later time?

Answer (score 0):

The factory pattern makes the most sense here: a `FacadeFactory` that is responsible for creating `Platform` and `Endpoint` instances and passing them into the `Facade` constructor. It is okay to do some amount of work in the `FacadeFactory`, but you can also delegate to a `PlatformFactory` and an `EndpointFactory` if necessary.

I would also eliminate the `Start`/`Stop` methods in `Facade` in favour of a simple constructor and a `Dispose` method. This ensures that constructed objects are in a valid state and uses a well-known pattern for releasing resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use a factory.

> Constructing/starting Platform/Endpoint are relatively complex and require things like getting certificate from the certificate store.

I would suggest that the Platform class should take care of starting itself, and the certificate store be made available via an injected service, to keep that sort of complexity out of the factory.

> If Builder/Factory are used; is this "too much work" for them? .

It is exactly the job of the factory to assemble all of the dependencies that the Endpoint needs and pass them to it. However, if starting a Platform or Endpoint requires logic (including and especially sequential coupling), I would suggest that sort of code belongs in the Platform and Endpoint classes themselves.

Comment: While I 100% agree that a factory is the place to do this, I can't agree with rewriting external libraries in order to have the platform and endpoint classes taking care of starting themselves.

Comment: If we're talking about external libraries or code that cannot be changed, it is always possible to *wrap*. So for example we could define class called `PlatformSession` that contains a `Platform` instance and is responsible for starting it up.

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

> 1. Initialize and start Platform/Endpoint in Facade's constructor.

Yes. This would be the ideal solution. At the end you'll have either a valid facade or an exception.

> 2. Start Platform/Endpoint in Facade's Start method.

This is not a great path to walk. It permits the facade to be in an uninitialised state. This weakens the assurance the facade provides, and as a consequence requires the user to verify the initialisation state before each use.

I consider this to be a union of nullable singleton, factory, and domain object. Its one thing, that might be null, that might need to be asked to change from null to real, that may or may not be available for actual use.

> 3. Use builder pattern to construct the Facade and initialize/start Platform/Endpoint in Build method.

If the facade has a complex configuration, or the configuration needs to be applied across several places in the application, then a builder is a perfectly legitimate way to enforce this.

> 4. Use factory pattern to construct the Facade and initialize/start Platform/Endpoint in Create method.

If the facade could have several backends then a factory is sensible. Alternately if the configuration is relatively simple this would also work.